# Converting XML to PDF on .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, xml, pdf, nfop

Can anyone help to solve this problem.

I can generate pdf files from xml using NFOP, which is a port from the Apache XML Project's FOP Java source to .NET's Visual J#.

But it doesn't work on .NET Framework 4.0.

Does anyone know an alternative solution?

Comment: Should be as simple as converting the J# code to C# code.

Comment: The problem is that there is no J# in .Net Framework 4!

Comment: Which is the reason you have to convert the code to C#.  I am giving you an alternative solution.  You could always just compile it against the .NET Framework 3.5 and be done with it.  A .NET Framework 4.0 application can import a .NET Framework 3.5 library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem this way:

1. Created an XSLT which transforms my XML to HTML using .NET XslCompiledTransform Class.
2. I used the **wkhtmltopdf** (you can find it [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)) and my PDF file was ready.

P.S. **wkhtmltopdf** is a tool that is based on **iText** libraries.